# Separate database for users with Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

the background for this is that we have an existing site which is going to be somewhat linked with the new one, so it would make a lot of sense to use the same user base.

So, we want to use the same user database. The way I tried is not working, adding two databases and providing the same Entity. This is also a different Symfony project, I could do it on the same one but it's more convenient to separate it because it might be running on different servers later on.

How can I make my user provider fetch the users from another MySQL database the easiest or best reliable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation for using multiple entity managers?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

You can set up configuration for multiple database connections and define which connection to use by default based on the bundle.

Alternatively you can explicitly choose which connection to use with

```
$this->get('doctrine')->getManager('<your custom manager name>');
```

If you're using a user provider specified in your `security.yml` (the approach used [here](http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/)) you can inject the userRepository for your alternate connection in the service definition.

```
  your.definition.of.user.provider:
    class: YourBundle\Entity\UserProvider
    arguments:
      - @=service('doctrine').getRepository('YourBundle:User', '<alternate manager name goes here>')
```

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't find a way to select a database to use in the security.yml. It also lead to the error: "Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'"

Comment: @TemporaryName I've updated the answer to show  how it might look if you're using the user provider as a service.

Comment: This looks promising but I don't know how to use it with your snippet. It looks different and I don't know how to use a user provider as a service.

Comment: What is your user provider class then?

Comment: `providers:
        default:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle\Entity\User
                property: email`
This is what I had used in pretty much every project so far. (Sorry for the formatting)

Comment: I'm not sure I can give you the exact answer, but I'd look into [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) and set up a provider like they explained, injecting your custom manager into it.